# How to structure Android App when using Jetpack Navigation's BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I've been trying to implement an app using Navigation component (in Kotlin). Following the Google CodeLab, I have (somewhat) succeed in making the barebones of the app using BottomNavigationBar.

But problem arise when I try implementing a login screen before user sees the whole Dashboard with the BottomNavBar. Codelabs and 'most' tutorial I seen about BottomNavbar didn't discuss how to implement a screen before the Navbar (like a Login Screen)

**So this is what I did:**

Have a **NavHostFragment** and **BottomNavView** inside the MainActivity

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_main"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then have all five of the screens (4 of which is the destinations of the Navbar, plus a Login Screen) inside the NavGraph, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaRie.jpg)

which basically take **LoginFragment** as the *startDestination* and hide the NavBar while inside **LoginFragment**. After user logs in, then we navigate them the actual intended start destination (which is **HomeFragment**) and pop LoginFragment from the backstack and finally show them the Navbar at HomeFragment.

This works fine at first glance, but then I notice the default backstack behaviour of BottomNavigation is gone (*Going to any of the destination will automatically pop current fragment* **and** *pressing back on any of the destination, except the startDestination, will first navigate to the startDestination*).

Instead, every destination was put into backstack and pressing back will pop the backstack one by one. So if you were to navigate `A -> B -> C -> D -> A`, pressing back will result in `A -> D -> C -> B -> A`. I did 'hackishly' solve it by overriding **onBackPressed** on MainActivity to this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val topLevelFrag = listOf(
            R.id.profileFragment,
            R.id.trackingListFragment,
            R.id.searchFragment)

    if(bind.bottomNav.isVisible) {
        val selectedId = bind.bottomNav.selectedItemId
        if(selectedId in topLevelFrag) {
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
            navController.popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, true)
            navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
            return
        } else if (selectedId == R.id.homeFragment) {
            //TODO show exit confirmation dialogbox
            finish()
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

which on the surface looks fine and similar to the default backstack management, but looking at the backstack if the user keeps on switching between the navbar destination without pressing Back, it will continuously grow.

So, I guess the question is what is the proper way to do this?

Other ways I can think of is maybe to make **HomeFragment** (aka intended startDestination) to be the *startDestination* and have **LoginFragment** as a destination in the NavGraph and whenever user want to perform some action that require them to be logged in, I will just navigate them to the fragment? This may work but what if I want the user to be logged in first?

Sorry for the long post, I hope I delivered my question clearly, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it's the "correct" way, but for simplicity and encapsulation, II would use a separate activity for the login screen and make it completely independent from the nav graph you already have. You would need to add it to the manifest and make it the MAIN/LAUNCHER Activity instead of the one that starts your nav graph. If you want the login screen not to stay on the back stack, have it call `finish()` on itself when it starts the main Activity. Then the main Activity and nav graph don't have to customize `onBackPressed`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah that's one way to do it. But I'm guessing they must have thought of this common case when building the Navigation component. I cant seem to find that, and very curious about it. But it's nice to know I have this as a last resort if I cant find any. Thank you!